# Ionic 2 - Change color at the top of the screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I built an app with Ionic 2 for Android.

I would like to know if it is possible with Ionic 2 to change the color that is at the top of the smartphone screen.

For example, in the Whatsapp image the top of the screen is green, and in my app it is black. I would like to switch to a lighter red, is this possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the color of the statusbar.

Put this into your `platform.ready block`:

```
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#34af23"); //change this to your color
    }
```

Probably you also need to import StatusBar from `ionic-native`:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your config.xml which is present in root of your project change these lines or add if not there.

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
 <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="your color" />`